# Node & Express User Auth - Postman returns Else statement

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, postman

I am having an issue with POSTing the data that I provide via Postman as it is returning my else string all the time. The Node server is running and it does not error particularly, so the syntax must be right.

```
const db = require("../models");

exports.login = (req, res) => {
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;

if (email && password) {
    const foundUser = db.users.findOne({
            where: {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }
        })

        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })

        .catch(err => {
            res.status(404).send({
                message: "Error retreiving User with email =" + email,
                err: err
            });
        });
} else {
    res.send('Please enter Email and Password!');
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe your email and password is empty or undefined , for make sure you got email and password try to ```console.log(email)``` and ```console.log(password)``` before if statement

Comment: **WARNING**: If you can find people by their password you're using *plain-text passwords* and this is a **serious problem**. Use [Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) to store these and validate them.

Comment: It's also 2020 so you can use `async` and `await` instead of the `then()` chain stuff that's no longer necessary.